# make R shiny to show multiple plots

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I have the following code, which produces a plot based on the user inputs. if, for example, the user selects three x variables, three plots shall be produced in the output. However, at the moment, only the plot relevant to the last selection is only produced.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

plt_func <- function(x,y){
  plt_list <- list()
  for (X_var in x){
    plt_list[[X_var]] <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(get(X_var), get(y)))+
      geom_point() + 
      labs(x = X_var, y = y)
  }
  
  return(plt_list)
}



ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(selectizeInput(inputId = "x",label = "X", choices = names(mtcars), multiple = T),
                 selectInput(inputId = "y",label = "Y", choices = names(mtcars),multiple = F),
                 actionButton("plot", label = "Plot")),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("finalplot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
plt <- eventReactive(input$plot, {
  req(input$x, input$y)
  x <- input$x
  y <- input$y
  
  do.call(plt_func, list(x,y))
  
})

output$finalplot <- renderPlot({
  plt()
})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

I wonder how I should tackle this issue.

Comment: `renderPlot` produces a single plot, not a series of three plots.  You need either multiple `renderPlot`s, `renderUI` or code that produces a single (perhaps facetted) plot.

Comment: when I use renderUI it produces an error as it can not render the plot. Can you explain more how should I use RenderUI or multiple renderPlot so that it changes dynamically based on user selection of variables

Answer (score 1):

To me, the easiest way to solve this problem is to create a module that will manage a single plot and then create the required number of instances of the module in the main server function.  You can read more about Shiny modules [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).

A Shiny module consists of two functions, a UI function and a server function.  These are paired by the fact that they share a common ID.  The ID is used to distinguish different instances of the same module.  Namespacing (the `ns` function) is used to distinguish instances of the same widget in different instances of the module.

The module UI function is straightforward.  It simply creates a `plotOutput`:

```
plotUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  plotOutput(ns("plot"))
}
```

The module server function takes three parameters: an `id` and the names of the x and y variables to plot.

```
plotServer <- function(id, Xvar, Yvar) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        req(Xvar)

        mtcars %>% 
          ggplot(aes(get(Xvar), get(Yvar))) +
            geom_point() + 
            labs(x = Xvar, y = Yvar)
      })
    }
  )
}
```

The main UI function creates the sidebar menu (there's no need for a Plot `actionButton` as Shiny's reactivity makes sure everything gets updated at the correct time) and a main panel that consists only of a `uiOutput`.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId = "x",label = "X", choices = names(mtcars), multiple = T),
      selectInput(inputId = "y",label = "Y", choices = names(mtcars), multiple = F)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("plotUI")
    )
  )
)
```

The main server function is where the magic happens. Every time there's a change to `input$x` or `input$y`, new instances of the module UI and server functions are created.  One for each selection in `input$x`.  The `id` for each module is simply an integer.  The appropriate column names are passed to each instance of the module server function.  A call to `renderUI` creates the UI for each instance of the module.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plotUI <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    tagList(
      lapply(1:length(input$x),
        function(i) {
          plotUI(paste0("plot", i))
        }
      )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(input$x, input$y), {
    plotServerList <- lapply(
      1:length(input$x),
      function(i) {
        plotServer(paste0("plot", i), input$x[i], input$y)
      }
    )
  })
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

# Plot module UI function
plotUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  plotOutput(ns("plot"))
}

# Plot module server function
plotServer <- function(id, Xvar, Yvar) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        req(Xvar)

        mtcars %>% 
          ggplot(aes(get(Xvar), get(Yvar))) +
            geom_point() + 
            labs(x = Xvar, y = Yvar)
      })
    }
  )
}

# Main UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId = "x",label = "X", choices = names(mtcars), multiple = T),
      selectInput(inputId = "y",label = "Y", choices = names(mtcars), multiple = F)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("plotUI")
    )
  )
)

# Main server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plotUI <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    tagList(
      lapply(1:length(input$x),
        function(i) {
          plotUI(paste0("plot", i))
        }
      )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(input$x, input$y), {
    plotServerList <- lapply(
      1:length(input$x),
      function(i) {
        plotServer(paste0("plot", i), input$x[i], input$y)
      }
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]