# Shiny Modules Reactive Plot

Tags: r, shiny, module, reactive

I have created a shiny output that has a reactive element and it works fine to produce a plot and table with the information that I need (see below).

What I would like, however, is to be able to put multiple ggplots stacked on top of one another depending on the number of items selected in the drop down as done [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73787656/make-r-shiny-to-show-multiple-plots) .

Attempting to recreate this with my data as well as reviewing articles and videos for hours has not worked. (I understand observeevent is necessary but is not seen in all code examples).

**Since the table works fine now it may not be needed in module component

Here is sample Data:

```
structure(list(est_IVE = c(72, 72, 72, 72, 47.3, 45.6, 45.8, 
46.6, 34, 34, 28, 43.1, 43.1, 37, 37, 33.8, 33.8, 37.3, 37.3, 
78.1, 78.1), lci_IVE = c(58.7, 58.7, 58.7, 58.7, 17.7, 4, 42.5, 
40.6, -40.3, -40.3, 19.8, 5.5, 5.5, 7.8, 7.8, 2.9, 2.9, 16, 16, 
-101.2, -101.2), uci_IVE = c(81, 81, 81, 81, 66.3, 69.2, 49, 
52.1, 68.9, 68.9, 35.4, 65.7, 65.7, 56.9, 56.9, 54.8, 54.8, 53.3, 
53.3, 97.6, 97.6), flu_type = c("bwis", "bwis", "bwis", "bwis", 
"bvic", "bvic", "bvic", "bvic", "bvic", "bvic", "h3n2", "h3n2", 
"h3n2", "h3n2", "h3n2", "h3n2", "h3n2", "h3n2", "h3n2", "h3n2", 
"h3n2"), ma_model = c("FE", "DL", "FE", "DL", "FE", "DL", "FE", 
"DL", "FE", "DL", "DL", "FE", "DL", "FE", "DL", "FE", "DL", "FE", 
"DL", "FE", "DL"), outcome_type = c("lab", "lab", "lab", "lab", 
"lab", "lab", "lab", "lab", "lab", "lab", "lab", "lab", "lab", 
"lab", "lab", "lab", "lab", "lab", "lab", "lab", "lab"), RG_type = c("genpop", 
"genpop", "genpop", "genpop", "65+", "65+", "genpop", "genpop", 
"65+", "65+", "genpop", "under5", "under5", "genpop", "genpop", 
"65+", "65+", "genpop", "genpop", "resp", "resp"), season = c("all", 
"all", "2013/14", "2013/14", "all", "all", "all", "all", "2019/20", 
"2019/20", "2016/17", "2016/17", "2016/17", "2016", "2016", "2015/16", 
"2015/16", "2015/16", "2015/16", "2015/16", "2015/16")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 
124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my code with reactive object that works fine when changing size of one plot (simplified with one multiple selection variable):

```
packages <- c('dplyr', 'tidyr','ggplot2','shiny')
invisible(lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE))


# _____ _____ _____


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Systematic Literature Review: Meta-Analysis'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('s', 'Season',                                            # Works to an extent, does not show values in years when we know they are there / go away
                  choices = unique(Data.0$season), multiple = TRUE),
      selectInput('rg', 'Risk Group',
                  choices = unique(Data.0$RG_type)),
      selectInput('ft', 'Virus (sub) Type',
                  choices = unique(Data.0$flu_type)),
      selectInput('ot', 'Outcome',
                  choices = unique(Data.0$outcome_type)),
      selectInput('mm', 'Model',
                  choices = unique(Data.0$ma_model))),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('table'),
      plotOutput('plot')
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  est.0 <- reactive({
    est.1 <- filter(Data.0,
                    RG_type == input$rg,
                    outcome_type == input$ot,
                    flu_type == input$ft,
                    season %in% input$s,
                    ma_model == input$mm)
    return(est.1)
  })
  output$table <- renderTable({
    est_tab <- est.0() %>% 
      select(est_IVE, lci_IVE,uci_IVE, season, k) %>% 
      rename(`Vaccine Effectiveness (%)` = est_IVE, `Lower CI (%)` = lci_IVE, `Upper CI (%)` = uci_IVE,
             Season = season)
    if(nrow(est_tab) > 0 ) {
      est_tab
    } else {Estimate = 'No Data Points'  # works but title of table is 'data'
    }
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    est.0() %>% 
      ggplot(.) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = lci_IVE, xend = uci_IVE,
                       y = season, yend = season),
                   size = 3, color = 'red') +
      geom_point(aes(x = est_IVE,
                     y = season),
                 size = 5, shape = 17) +
      geom_label(aes(x = est_IVE, y = season,
                     label = round(as.numeric(est_IVE), digits = 1)),
                 vjust = 2) +
      geom_label(aes(x = lci_IVE, y = season,
                     label = round(as.numeric(lci_IVE), digits = 1)),
                 vjust = 2) +
      geom_label(aes(x = uci_IVE, y = season,
                     label = round(as.numeric(uci_IVE), digits = 1)),
                 vjust = 2) +
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_rect('#caf5fc'),
            panel.border = element_rect(color = 'black', fill = NA, size = 2),
            axis.title = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, face = 'bold'),
            axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Attempt to create an R Shiny module code that will allow me to have multiple stacked ggplots depending on number of seasons selected.

```
# _____ ____ _____

mod_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput(ns('table')),
    plotOutput(ns('plot'))
  )
}

mod_server <- function(id) { # Svar, Vvar [REMOVED] - Svar (season) Vvar (virus subtype)
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      # req(Var?)
      est.0 <- reactive({
        est.1 <- filter(Data.0,
                        RG_type == input$rg,
                        outcome_type == input$ot,
                        flu_type == input$ft,
                        # season %in% input$s,
                        ma_model == input$mm)
        return(est.1)
      })
      output$table <- renderTable({
        est_tab <- est.0() %>% 
          select(season == input$s) %>% 
          select(est_IVE, lci_IVE,uci_IVE, season, k) %>% 
          rename(`Vaccine Effectiveness (%)` = est_IVE, `Lower CI (%)` = lci_IVE, `Upper CI (%)` = uci_IVE,
                 Season = season)
        if(nrow(est_tab) > 0 ) {
          est_tab
        } else {Estimate = 'No Data Points'
        }
      })
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        est.0() %>% 
          select(season == input$s) %>% 
          ggplot(.) +
          geom_segment(aes(x = lci_IVE, xend = uci_IVE,
                           y = flu_type, yend = flu_type),
                       size = 3, color = 'red') +
          geom_point(aes(x = est_IVE,
                         y = flu_type),
                     size = 5, shape = 17) +
          geom_label(aes(x = est_IVE, y = flu_type,
                         label = round(as.numeric(est_IVE), digits = 1)),
                     vjust = 2) +
          geom_label(aes(x = lci_IVE, y = flu_type,
                         label = round(as.numeric(lci_IVE), digits = 1)),
                     vjust = 2) +
          geom_label(aes(x = uci_IVE, y = flu_type,
                         label = round(as.numeric(uci_IVE), digits = 1)),
                     vjust = 2) +
          theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                panel.background = element_rect('#caf5fc'),
                panel.border = element_rect(color = 'black', fill = NA, size = 2),
                axis.title = element_blank(),
                axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, face = 'bold'),
                axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
      })
    }
  )
}


# _____ ____ _____

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('s', 'Season',                                           
                  choices = unique(Data.0$season), multiple = TRUE),
      selectInput('rg', 'Risk Group',
                  choices = unique(Data.0$RG_type)),
      selectInput('ft', 'Virus (sub) Type',
                  choices = unique(Data.0$flu_type), multiple = TRUE),
      selectInput('ot', 'Outcome',
                  choices = unique(Data.0$outcome_type)),
      selectInput('mm', 'Model',
                  choices = unique(Data.0$ma_model))),
    
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput('mod_ui')
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mod_ui <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    tagList(
      lapply(1:length(input$s),
             function(i) {
               mod_ui(paste0('plot', i))
             }
             )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$s, { # input$ft c(input$s, input$ft)
    mod_server <- lapply(
      1:length(input$s),
      function(i) {
        mod_server(paste0('plot', i), input$s[i]) # ,input$s[i], input$y  (~ft)
      }
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As always, thank you - this community rocks

Comment: You should minimize your code to increase your chance to get an answer. Not everybody wants to install this bunch of packages.

Comment: its not clear at the moment which input namespace is controlling which module?

Comment: Is this in regards to wrapping ns() around tables and variables? Based on the code provided in the link above, it appeared as if this example would not require one. -- Ie within the select input there were no ns() only in the plot portion of ui_module